# cakephp 3.0 model filed form hyphen underscore

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Today I ran into this problem. There should be some simple solution, but I guess I am too tired to find it...

In one of my tables there is a field 'workplace_address'. I would like to update it via ajax.

My input field is `echo $this->Form->input('workplace_address);` which generates this:

```
<input type="text" id="workplace-address" name="workplace_address">
```

The controller gets the posted data, so I have `$this->request->data['workplace-address']`

Still the submitted data is missing after patching data

```
$contact = $this->Contacts->patchEntity($contact, $this->request->data);
```

Is this some hyphen / underscore problem, or I just do not see something obvious?

Comment: Yes, it is, the submitted fieldname is simply wrong, whatever AJAX script you are using is behaving wrongly, using the elements `id` instead of the `name` attribute.

Comment: @ndm Oh, gee, that is why I was not able to find the problem on the PHP side... Definitely this is the time to go to bed. Thanks.